# Zend\Mail\Message Issue

Tags: zend-framework2

Im using ZF2's Message class to try to send emails. However, after executing the code below, the page tries to redirect and after a minute or so gives me a "local host has timed out" error. Any ideas?

```
    $message = new Message();
    $message->addTo('ToEmail@gmail.com')
      ->addFrom('FromEmail@gmail.com')
      ->setSubject('Greetings and Salutations!')
      ->setBody("Sorry, I'm going to be late today!");

    // Setup SMTP transport using LOGIN authentication
    // Setup SMTP transport using PLAIN authentication over TLS
    $transport = new SmtpTransport();
    $options   = new SmtpOptions(array(
        'name'              => 'localhost',
        'host'              => 'localhost',
        'port'              => 8888, // Notice port change for TLS is 587
        'connection_class'  => 'plain',
        'connection_config' => array(
            'username' => 'FromEmail@gmail.com',
            'password' => 'FromPassword',
            'ssl'      => 'tls',
        ),
    ));
    $transport->setOptions($options);
    $transport->send($message);
```

Comment: Just curious, but based on your settings are you able to telnet localhost 8888 and get a response? Normal SMTP settings are port 25 or 587(TLS).

Comment: Yeah I can telnet to 8888. I tried with both 25 and 587 and it couldn't connect. I also tried executing the code again and rather than getting a "local host timed out" error, I'm getting the following "Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data."

Comment: Since you're using SMTP, can you try using that server as the outgoing mail server on your desktop mail client to see if sending even works from there?

Comment: I'm on a Mac so I configured the Mail app to send messages but didn't know of a way to see if the message was actually sent. Therefore, I used the terminal to run the following: mail -s "Testing" `whoami`@`hostname`. It seems like it has the same functionality. Using this, I was able to send and receive mail.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to send email using Zend Framework 2.0. Please follow the below set of codes.

```
$options = new Mail\Transport\SmtpOptions(
                                    'smtp_options' => array(
            'name' => 'localhost',
            'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
            'port'=> 587,
            'connection_class' => 'login',
            'connection_config' => array(
                'username' => '<your gmail account username>@gmail.com',
                'password' => '<your gmail account password>',
                'ssl'      => 'tls'
            ),
        )
                            );


                            $content = 'Message to be sent in the email.(goes here)';  

                            // make a header as html  
                            $html = new MimePart($content);  
                            $html->type = "text/html";  
                            $body = new MimeMessage();  
                            $body->setParts(array($html)); 

                            // instance mail   
                            $mail = new Mail\Message();  
                            $mail->setBody($body); // will generate our code html from template.phtml  
                            $mail->setFrom('FromEmail@gmail.com');  
                            $mail->setTo('ToEmail@gmail.com');
                            $mail->setSubject('Subject for sending email.');

                            $transport = new Mail\Transport\Smtp($options);
                            $transport->send($mail);
```

Let me know if you face any problem at dineshs@mindfiresolutions.com